# React rerendering overflowed component causes page to jump

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-goldwasser-se8gi?file=/src/App.js) for reference.

When the button is pressed, the state is changed and #container1 is replaced with #container2. The page remains at the same height and the outer containers remain at the same height. However, after the page is scrolled down (necessary to access the button) and the button is pressed, the page is scrolled up to somewhere in the middle. I would expect the page to not move given that no layout was changed, only some of the text.

I need the containers to have fixed height even when the text inside overflows, and it seems that the overflow is causing this page jump bug.

Fun facts:

- If #container2 only has 1 div element the bug doesn't seem to happen.
- The bug only happens the first time the state is changed from #container1 to #container2, but if you scroll up any amount while viewing #container1, the bug will appear the next time the state is changed.
- Size does matter. I can reproduce the bug in the editor and in "Toggle Responsive Preview" modes with "Tablet" or "Desktop" sizes. If I view the page in a new tab the bug will not appear.
- I used Chrome but a quick test shows that the bug also appears on Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here :-

`<div id="container1">`

Your `container1` will not restrict itself to height of it's parent unless you explicitly tell it to.

Change it to this :-

`<div id="container1" style={{ height: "100%" }}>`